# Java insertion sorting String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically through comparing their first letters. I can get an insertion sort working with integers but when I change the integers to strings and reference the integer values of the first character for comparison purposes it stops working. Here is my code, could someone help me learn what I have done wrong?

```
public static boolean cSL(String a, String b)
{
    int aN = (int)(a.charAt(0));
    int bN = (int)(b.charAt(0));
    if(aN < 97) aN += 32;//make case insensitive
    if(bN < 97) bN += 32;
    return(aN < bN);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] sort = {"ai", "ff", "gl", "bw", "dd", "ca"};
    for( int c = 1; c < sort.length; c++ )
    {
        String key = sort[c];
        int count = c - 1;
        while (count >= 0 && cSL(key, sort[count]))
        {
            sort[count + 1] = sort[count];
            count--;
        }
        sort[count + 1] = sort[c];
    }
    //print out the array
    for(int n = 0; n < sort.length; n++)
        System.out.print(sort[n] + " ");

}
```

This should output "ai bw ca dd ff gl " but instead it prints "ai gl gl gl ff gl "

Comment: you probably need to replace `sort[count + 1] = sort[c];` with `sort[count + 1] = key;`

Comment: Didn't see that. I don't think it would change anything besides making the code look nicer though, because key and sort[c] reference the same value within each iteration of the loop.

Comment: FYI, you're making it more difficult to read with the whole `c` and `count` thing. Why make count `c-1` then use `count + 1`? `count + 1` *is* `c`; no?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg's suggestion fixes your issue

Comment: @Ben Well when I run it it prints the exact output you expect from it. Because you overwrite `sort[c]` in the first pass through the while loop with  a new value.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg Yup, just tried it, and realized what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the help and I'm sorry I doubted your original advice.

Comment: The array is changing as you go; key and sort[c] diverge.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! All I did was edited the `while` loop and commented the next line below it.

```
public static boolean cSL(String a, String b)
{
    int aN = (int)(a.charAt(0));
    int bN = (int)(b.charAt(0));
    if(aN < 97) aN += 32;//make case insensitive
    if(bN < 97) bN += 32;
    return aN < bN;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] sort = {"ai", "ff", "gl", "bw", "dd", "ca"};
    for( int c = 1; c < sort.length; c++ )
    {
        String key = sort[c];
        int count = c - 1;
        while (count >= 0 && cSL(key, sort[count]))
        {
            String temp = sort[count+1];
            sort[count + 1] = sort[count];
            sort[count] = temp;
            count--;
        }
        //sort[count + 1] = sort[c]; This Line is in comment because it is not needed
    }
        //print out the array
        for(int n = 0; n < sort.length; n++)
            System.out.print(sort[n] + " ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After while loop there is logical error in this line

```
 sort[count + 1] = sort[c];
```

you are using sort[c] where array is being manipulated by the above while loop and indexes are shuffled. Instead you should use the key variable, you used to store current value to be compared as that is over written by loop.

```
 sort[count + 1] = key;
```

This makes the code work perfect. Hope this helps